# Intersection of collection of subspaces contained in a given subspace but every finite intersection is not

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional vector space and $W \subset V$ a proper subspace.
I mush exhibit an infinite sequence of subspaces $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ such that
$\cap_{i = 1}^{\infty} Y_i \subset W$ but
$\cap_{i = 1}^{n} Y_i \not\subset W$ for every $n$.

I don't know how to solve this but I thought about something which might be interesting, i.e. what happens if $W=\{0\}$? In such a case I think (but pls correct me if I am wrong) that I should just take
$Y_i = \text{sp} \{ y_i, y_{i+1}, \dots \}$, where $(y_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is an infinite linearly independent set.

Comment: If $W$ has finite codimension in $V$, then such a sequence doesn't exist. Otherwise you can reduce it to $W = \{0\}$ by considering the space $V/W$ (and your idea works).

Comment: @DanielFischer So you mean that if $W$ has finite codimension then the statement I am supposed to prove is actually false?

Comment: Yup. Move it to $V/W$. You have a bijection between the subspaces $W \subset Y \subset V$ and the subspaces $X$ of $V/W$ that respects intersection etc. So you can find a sequence $Y_i$ (if $(Y_i)$ works, the so does $(Z_i)$ where $Z_i = Y_i + W$) as desired if and only if you can find a sequence $X_i$ of subspaces in $V/W$ with $\bigcap X_i = \{0\}$ and $\bigcap_{i = 1}^n X_i \neq \{0\}$ for every $n$. Can you see why that is impossible if $\dim V/W < \infty$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes I think I do. If I have a collection of subspaces $(X_i)_i$ of a *finite-dimensional* vector space such that $\cap_{i=1}^n X_i \neq \{0\}$ for every $n$, then I could consider $d_n := dim(X_1 \cap \dots X_n)$. $d_0$ is some integer, $n \mapsto d_n$ is non-increasing and $d_n > 0$ for every $n$. But such $d_n$ is eventually constant, i.e., say, there exists an $N$ such that $d_n = \bar{d}$ for every $n>N$. So $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i = \cap_{i=1}^{N} X_i$ which cannot be the trivial subspace. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes. The good old "every non-increasing sequence of natural numbers is eventually constant" strikes again.

Comment: Thanks all clear now!

Comment: @DanielFischer If you wanna write an answer I ll be happy to upvote and accept.